# Serverside validation in uploadify

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file-upload, uploadify

Im using uploadify, everthing is working fine but im stucked at Server side validation,

Suppose if the user uploads multiple files , if the total size of all files exceeds some 15 mb then i need to throw an error on the screen that max limit is 15 mb. Is it possible in Uploadify

Code which i have tried:

html:

```
<form>
    <div id="div_errorLog"></div>
    <div id="queue"></div>
    <input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" multiple="true">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php $timestamp = time();?>
    $(function() {
        $('#file_upload').uploadify({
            'formData'     : {
                    'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
                    'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>'
            },
            'auto'     : true,
            'fileTypeExts' : '*.jpg; *.mp3; *.wma; *.wav; *.m4a; *.amr; *.3ga; *.flv; *.mov; *.dat;*.avi;*.mpeg; *.ram; *.mp4; *.wmv; *.asf; *.swf; *.m3u; *.3gp; *.mpg; *.divx; *.rm; *.pps; *.zip; *.rar; *.gz; *.txt; *.exe; *.msi; *.tgz; *.scr; *.dot; *.docx; *.chm;*.jar; *.torrent; *.xlsx; *.ngr; *.7z; *.001; *.002; *.003; *.004; *.005; *.006; *.007;*.008; *.009; *.010; *.011; *.012; *.013; *.014;*.015; *.016; *.017; *.018; *.019; *.020; *.ai; *.psd; *.cdr; *.pptx; *.apk; *.ipa; *.pkg; *.cbr; *.cbz',
            'fileSizeLimit' : '15360KB',
            'multi'    : false,
            'uploader' : 'uploadify.php',
            'queueSizeLimit' : 1,
            'uploadLimit' : 1,
            'onUploadError' : function(file, errorCode, errorMsg, errorString) {
                    alert('The file ' + file.name + ' could not be uploaded: ' + errorString);
                }, 
            'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
                    alert('The file ' + file.name + ' was successfully uploaded');
                    window.location.replace("");
                } 
        });
    });
</script>
```

uploadify.php

```
if (!empty($_FILES) && $_POST['token'] == $verifyToken) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
        $var_UniqueFileName = strtotime("now").'_'.$_FILES["Filedata"]["name"];
    $targetFile = "uploads/".$var_UniqueFileName;
    // Validate the file type
    $fileTypes = array("mp3", "wma", "wav", "m4a", "amr", "3ga", "flv", "mov", "dat", "avi",
            "mpeg", "ram", "mp4", "wmv", "asf", "swf", "m3u", "3gp", "mpg", "divx", "rm", "vob", 
            "rmvb", "f4v", "jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "bmp", "png", "doc", "csv", "xls", "rtf", "ppt",
            "pdf", "pps", "zip", "rar", "gz", "txt", "exe", "msi", "tgz", "scr", "dot", "docx", "chm", 
            "jar", "torrent", "xlsx", "ngr", "7z", "001", "002", "003", "004", "005", "006", "007", "008", 
            "009", "010", "011", "012", "013", "014", "015", "016", "017", "018", "019", "020", "ai", "psd", 
            "cdr", "pptx", "apk", "ipa", "pkg", "cbr", "cbz"); // File extensions
    $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
    if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {

             move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);

        echo '1';
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid file type.';
    }
}
```

How can i implement the server side validation?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php.  just loop through file sizes to get sum.

Comment: im using uploadify.. Here how can i loop through the $FILES, As i think uplodify is calling single ajax for every file..